# VideoView restarting after the phone is locked android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using a videoView and everything works fine, the problem is that when I am seeing the video and I lock the phone. The screen go black( this is normal since the phone is locked) but the sound of the video starts,

Anyone knows how to solve it?

I tested this but still not working

```
vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    vv.pause();
    vv.stopPlayback();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem,

The problem was that i was using

```
vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0)
        {
          vv.start();
        }
}
```

And when the phone pause it, It pass over this function because it prepare the next session.

I just control it with a boolean,

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    reanimar = true;
}
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    reanimar = false;
}
```